# qemu-system-x86_64.exe': Invalid argument 3:06 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 22

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, windows-10

the Android emulator was working on my computer (for months), though it was running really slow, today I gave the process real time priority and it was working faster, but after I rebooted my computer I am now getting Emulator: Process finished with exit code 22.  I have rebooted the machine, uninstalled android studio and reinstalled it. Removed the emulator and added it back. I still keep getting this error.   Looking for advice?

Windows 10 64bit

16gb

i5-7300u

Android Studio 3.5.3

JRE 1.8.0_202

JVM OpenJDK 64

```
Well that bounty offer was a complete waste. If anyone in the future comes to
this problem, please note I am reformatting my laptop, it's apparently the only solution.
```

Comment: Have you tried to wipe the data on the virtual device?

Comment: yes, I even completed removed android studio and the emulator, rebooted and reinstalled them.  Tried googling exit code 22, and couldn't find anything.  So there is nothing to go on that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below points

Open Android Virtual Device Manager
Click on Options for Virtual device
Step 1: Wipe Data
Step 2: Cold Boot Now

Comment: I have already done, and still no joy, but now I am getting something really weird.   I decided to update HAXM and now I am getting

This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology, please hyper-v is disabled in windows features.... it is disabled, this computer was supporting the android emulator.

Comment: I am giving you the bounty even though it was not the solution to the problem nor was there any followup, better to give you the points than watch them disappear into the ether.  Your solution may help somebody else with a less complicated issue.

Comment: Thank you @jeremiah. Not sure why it is not worked for you. I'll come with the better approach next time.